# How do I install raw drivers for my Panasonic LX100 on Windows 10?

Tags: raw, windows, panasonic-lumix

I can't seem to find RW2 codec support for my Panasonic LX100 for Windows 10 anywhere. Or, rather, everywhere I can find drivers that might work don't seem to support Windows 10. Has anyone found a good solution for this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you must view your raw images directly with the Windows viewer rather than with a Windows 10 application that can interpret .rw2 files, such as Lightroom, RawTherapee, Irfanview, etc?

Comment: @MichaelClark I assume it's to show thumbnails in Windows Explorer.

Comment: @scottbb I'd rather not assume.

Comment: Yeah--I'd like native support; Explorer, Image Viewer. I can start using a tool, but I'd like the files to render in everyday contexts, too.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem with my GX8 and wanted to have some kind of preview in Windows Explorer. I searched for hours and finally decided to try out and then buy [FastPictureViewer Codec Pack](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/codecs/).

It's very fast, but the preview image is not 100% accurate (you can see that when zooming in).

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone. [This thread ("Microsoft Camera Codec Pack for Windows 10 64-bit") at answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/microsoft-camera-codec-pack-for-windows-10-64-bit/00a1ae0a-936e-42fd-b928-ca38eb2fd8f6) seems to indicate that as of June 25, 2016, there still was no solution from Microsoft.

The basic gist is to try to install the Windows 8.1 Camera Codec Pack. A straightforward installation attempt doesn't seem to work. It seems that users were able to edit the 8.1 codec pack with a MSI editor (such as Orca), and remove the "Launch Condition". They were then able to install the MSI, and view their raw images in Windows Explorer and Photo Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know anyone who hasn't been in your shoes :) I was recommended recently this software:  http://www.aftershotpro.com/en/pages/rw2-file/  and it works like a charm , not only for RW2 but for almost all RAW files (NEF, CR2, ARW...). Try it yourself and let me know how it works out